# Array of integers contains undefined value

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I'm trying to return a multiplication table as a string based of the number parameter of the function but the first element always returns undefined.

### *My Code*

```js
function multiTable(number) {
  let arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
  let multiplication;
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    if (element > 0) {
      multiplication += `${element} * ${number} = ${element * number}\n`;
    }
  });
  return multiplication;
}

let table = multiTable(5);
console.log(table);
//Returns undefined1 * 5 = 5 2 * 5 = 10 .....etc
```

I'm new to JavaScript is there something I'm missing?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+undefined+appears+at+start+of+string) of [Why is there "undefined" text in the beginning of my string?](/q/41031256/4642212).

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to declare `let arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);` when a simple `for` loop would do

Comment: The function can be shortened to ``const multiTable = (number) => Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, index) => `${index + 1} * ${number} = ${index * number + number}`).join("\n");``

Comment: @SebastianSimon that is correct but I am not sure it would be particularly understandable or useful to someone who wrote "*I'm new to JavaScript*" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way you are initialising your `multiplication` variable the initial value is `undefined`.

you instead need to initialise `multiplication` as an empty string.

**What you are doing.**

```js
let multiplication; // undefined
multiplication += "test string" // 'undefinedtest string'
```

**What you should be doing**

```js
let multiplication = ""; // ''
multiplication += "test string" // 'test string'
```